# How to disable security warning in chrome using selenium webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

[image]

I am getting this error while i run in chrome(version-35). when i check it in version-33 , it does not show up.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771922/protractor-error-message-unsupported-command-line-flag-in-chrome/23816922#23816922).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816922/1389374) answer or rolling back the chrome version is your best bet.

Apologies for adding this as an answer and not a comment, don't haven enough votes for adding comments to other's posts.