# watir unsupported command-line flag

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, watir

I am creating a chrome browser using the following code snippets -

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 600
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :http_client => client
```

I encountered an error running my tests using Chrome. The error displays beneath the address bar in the launched browser:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag
>   --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.

Is there a simple way to make this message disappear ? Ideally, I want to do it with ruby code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771922/protractor-error-message-unsupported-command-line-flag-in-chrome/23816922#23816922) for why that error is occurring. The TL;DR of it is that ignoring bad SSL certificates can lead to some nasty security holes. But, since you are in a testing environment where this is what you want, you can update this line:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --test-type]
```

If you want certificate errors, change it to `%w[]`

Comment: Perfect!!! How did you learn this ? Is it there in the documentation or in some blog ? I tried googling and did not get anything close to your answer.

Comment: @stack1 I had to go into the Selenium and water web driver source code to find it. They're both on Github.

Comment: I found it one here: http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/ and then verified that it would work by looking at the source code here: https://github.com/vertis/selenium-webdriver/blob/8f4aefa604e76b24085c91f70f97a093e40a08d6/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb